# OpenCL segfault when using CPU

Tags: opencl

I'm working on implementing an FFT algorithm using OpenCL (specifically, the algorithm from *OpenCL in Action.*  It runs fine on two different NVIDIA GPU's (the Tesla K20c and the GeForce GTX 650) but gives me a segmentation fault when I run it on my Intel CPU.

I've located the problem in the kernel code, but it doesn't make sense.  The only two lines that give an error on their inclusion is the last two writes to local memory in the block below.  No other write to memory causes a problem for the CPU, and they don't cause a problem on the GPU.

```
__kernel void fft_init(__global float2 *g_data, __local float2 *l_data, 
                   uint points_per_group, uint size, int dir) {

    uint4 br, index;
    uint points_per_item, g_addr, l_addr, i, fft_index, stage, N2;
    float2 x1, x2, x3, x4, sum12, diff12, sum34, diff34;

    points_per_item = points_per_group/get_local_size(0);
    l_addr = get_local_id(0) * points_per_item;
    g_addr = get_group_id(0) * points_per_group + l_addr;

    for(i=0; i<points_per_item; i+=4) {

     ...

        l_data[l_addr] = sum12 + sum34;
        l_data[l_addr+1] = diff12 + diff34;
        l_data[l_addr+2] = sum12 - sum34;
        l_data[l_addr+3] = diff12 - diff34; 

        l_addr+= 4;
}
```

I also know that the problem isn't the `l_addr + {2,3}` as further in the kernel the array is accessed by at least `l_addr + 4`.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this before, or have any ideas on how I can fix it?  To run the kernel I use EnqueueNDRangeKernel and when setting the argument for the local memory array I'm using the entire local memory size available.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that you are accessing past the end of the array that has been allocated. What is the size you expect `l_data` array to be (in bytes) and what value are you passing in clSetKernelArg size argument? Also, what does clGetDeviceInfo for CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE return? Does it fit? Finally, if your usage of local memory is fixed-size (rather than dynamic) a better form is: `__local float localBuffer[1024];` rather than using a kernel argument.

Comment: The l_data array is the exact size of LOCAL_MEM_SIZE, as returned by GetDeviceInfo.  In this case it's 32768, and that's the number I'm passing to clSetKernelArg.  The pointer argument for clSetKernelArg is NULL, and I am going to play with that right now to see if that's a problem.

Local memory is dynamic, not fixed, as I use the whole local memory available to the device - but I'll look into a way to do that from inside the kernel.

Comment: Ignore what I said about the NULL argument above, I found out that's the way it's supposed to be.

I've found that in the smallest case, l_addr is never larger than `get_local_id(0)`.  Since the number of work items per group is much smaller than LOCAL_MEM_SIZE, I cannot understand why accessing `l_data[l_addr+3]` is accessing past the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure why it works, but I've managed to figure out a solution.  With this program, the work group size needed to be 1024.  The two NVIDIA cards already had this as their max work group size but the Intel CPU had a max work group size of 4096 (both as returned by `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(...CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE...)`.  This is why the GPU's worked and the CPU didn't.

Again, not sure why this manages to make the code work but it's a fix and I'll take it.